# RSpec Deprecated

Tags: rspec, rspec2, deprecated

I am working on a few tests and each time I am running them I receive the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: you are using a deprecated constant that will
be removed from a future version of RSpec.

C:/Sites/injixo/spec/views/me_home_spec.rb:1in 'require'

*Rspec is deprecated
*Rspec is the new top-level module in RSpec-2
```

I have the latest version 2.6.1 of RSpec installed so I am unsure why this warning is appearing. Can anyone shed some light on this matter and how I might go about removing it.

Thanks
JP

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is most likely in `spec/spec_helper.rb`, which is probably required by your spec. The top-level module is now called `RSpec` with a capital S. For your question, you must have typed some of the error message by hand instead of copy-and-pasting it. Your spec_helper should look something like this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
    ...
end
```

Comment: would be nice if the warning stated that!

Answer (score 4):

I came across this error by using guard. I simply had to change

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2 do
```

to

```
guard 'rspec' do
```

in the `Guardfile`.